# Any online tutorial/example for using hibernate with spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Is there any online tutorial/example or project which shows how to implement hibernate with spring MVC

Comment: Did you even try googling? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fresh, but quite detailed:
http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3577101/Developing-J2EE-Applications-Using-Hibernate-Annotations-and-Spring-MVC.htm

Answer (score 0):

When you download the official [spring distribution](http://s3.amazonaws.com/dist.springframework.org/release/SPR/spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE-with-docs.zip) you'll find the source code of a project called  [petclinic](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html) which illustrates how to use techniques such as hibernate.

Comment: is that petclinic a web based app which i can see through browser or its java app like desktop app

Comment: The hibernate parts are exemplified irregardless of web- or desktop application.